# Multiprocessing does not work in python. Script keeps running, does not stop

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pool

I would like to use pool.apply or pool.map. I tried to run several examples but none of those work. The code keeps running and does not provide any errors. Might this have anything to do with the settings of my system?

I tried to use several simple examples.

one of the examples i tried to run:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def doubler(number):
    return number * 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = [5, 10, 20]
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    Print(pool.map(doubler, numbers))
```

Python keeps running, did not provide any results.

Comment: Your example works fine on my machine. Can you describe what the issue is in more detail?

Comment: Are you on Windows by any chance? If so have a look at the sections in the Multiprocessing regarding freeze_support etc which are Windows specific.